# CodeIgniter: Is possible to have current page link by pagination library?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I have created pagination item by CodeIgniter pagination library with following code:

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links()
```

Everything is working well.

Now i want to load data by ajax and i have done already ajax part. But problem is to make `clicked item` as a `current item` and to arrange link for `current item` as it is no longer current.

Suppose i have a pagination as following:

```
[1] 2 [3] [4] [5] [6] [>] [Last >]
```

Now 2 is current item and 4 is clicked item.

I have checked [CodeIgniter Pagination library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php), but it doesn't have any option to enable or disable current page link. Is it possible to have current page link without modifying the library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get pagination with data from server side and replace with current one

Comment: what you want to do with current link? can you say it clear please

Answer (score 1):

I take it all back. The Pagination library will need to be changed.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php

Line 560

```
$output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close
```

Will need to be replaced with

```
$append = $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
$output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->base_url.$append.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
```

That should do it.

Comment: Sorry. I need href attribute too. CI have tag open and close config in their class, but it will not create your link :(

Comment: sorry, i don't want to modify the library. because my client might not allow me to modify that. :(

Comment: I fear that's your only option my friend. Unless you use a javascript solution to modify the ui. I will add some pseudo code later to demonstrate how that could be achieved if your unsure.

Comment: Failing any of that, you could just create your own pagination library by duplicating the original but with the slight modifications above...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i've voted your answer. But this in not what i need. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify anything on server side. just use plain old vanila jquery.

Here's how to do it.

Let's say i wrapped the links in a `<div id="pagination"></div>`

- Now, to call ajax, use `jQuery(body).on('click','#pagination a', function(e){....})`.
  Here in this code, `jQuery(this)` will refer to the link that was clicked.
- Next, after successful call, remove the `active` (or any other class that is given ) from **all** the links. like `jQuery('#pagination a').removeClass('active')`.
- Next, if you still remember, `jQuery(this)` still refered to the current clicked item. (better save it as `var current = jQuery(this)` at the start of the clicked even so that the reference does not change. Now, just add the class. `jQuery(current).addClass('active')`

You are done! No need to do anything fancy anything in server side. Sometimes client side is enough.

P.S. i forgot how CI renders the pagination links. if you give the links, i can write the actual code.

Comment: When you are removing `active` class, that item should have link now and when you are adding `active` class, then you should remove it's link. Do you get it?

Comment: why you need to remove the links i don't understand. just use `preventDefault()` if the link matches with current url and don't call the ajax.

Comment: Ok. But by default active item dont have any link it just have a `strong` text. Then how could i get the current link.

Comment: depends on lot of factors. are you ushing `pushState` of browser history? can this link be get from a GET request? (e.g. `http://example.com/controller/method/page/3` by typing in the address bar.) are you allowing it?

Comment: Ok. I have 3 tab and all tab have pagination items and i have added my ajax code in jsFiddle. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/itskawsar/pxW2n/

Now please tell me what to do. Thanks

Comment: check Ian Brindley's answer. the solution lies there.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($this->pagination);` everything is inside

then if you check Pagination.php library you have these params available too:

```
var $cur_tag_open = '';
var $cur_tag_close = '';
```

so try calling them when initializing pagination

```
$pagination['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current-link">';
$pagination['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
$this->pagination->initialize($pagination); //now current link should be wrapped into the <span class="current-link"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to change anything in the Pagination library. You just need to use the **uri_segment()** function.
The Pagination library takes an argument as follows:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5;
```

The default value is 3. [Use a value that will work with your URI structure].

This variable is used along with the uri_segment() function to determine the current page, in the latest version of CodeIgniter 2.1.4 you will find it starting on *line 142* in the **Pagination.php** library.

The appropriate uri_segment for the page identifier could be calculated as follows, if using a URI like this one: http://example.com/controller/function/page/*20* then you can get the current page as follows,

```
$page = $this->uri_segment(4);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You really dont need to change anything.
Once you have your automatic page set

> $page = 2 // Page should be set automatically

Now try this

> $config["cur_page"] = $page;